# SBS 2011 folder redirection

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, folder-redirection

I would like to disable folder redirection for a user in SBS 2011, but I also want to have desktop and all other folders moved back to client machine.

The problem is when I disable folder redirection and restart the machine I see clear destop on the on the client machine desktop. When I login to server as this user, the desktop is fully loaded on the server as I expect it to load on the client machine.

How to restore folders to client machine?

Comment: Are you using roaming profiles at all?

Comment: @syneticon-dj no we don't

Comment: Should we use roaming profiles together with folder redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing or disabling the *Small Business Server Folder Redirection Policy* your location redirections should be reverted back to the user's profile directories. The contents should be copied back into the profile directories if the *"Move the contents ... to the new location"* option was checked upon the original GPO setup. Since it is not moving automatically for some reason, you just can copy (or move) the redirected folder's contents either manually or using a logon script back into the user's local profile.